# Using Smart contract with web3- Not able to send transaction sucessfully

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, parity, remix

I tried to send ether from multiaddress, for that I have created one contract. Contract is deployed successfully in ropsten testnet.

I have started service in background using this command.

```
parity --warp --chain ropsten --rpcapi 'eth,net,web3,personal'
```

### Contract Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract ERC20 {
  function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract Airdrop {
  function drop(ERC20 token, address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
      token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Contract Deployed URL: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x84265173B2386D674ABA59b35D8C2A77C8A88181

Tried to apply send_transaction using Web3Js but Not able to success.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const abi = require('human-standard-token-abi') 

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));


// Define the contract addresses and the contract instance
const contractAddress = '0x84265173B2386D674ABA59b35D8C2A77C8A88181'
//const contract = new web3.eth.contract(abi, contractAddress)

var contractAbi = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var contract = contractAbi.at(contractAddress);
// suppose you want to call a function named myFunction of myContract

/*console.log(web3.eth.accounts[0]);
return false;*/

contract.drop.sendTransaction('0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57',["0x2885f9904f3d1790ba53009bc9e0baae377d67df","0x7b7cd7d5cee9fb36b7995a3d81df0122a0b1af4a"],[100,200],{
    from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
    gas:4000000},function (error, result){ //get callback from function which is your transaction key
    if(!error){
        console.log(result);
    } else{
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

Please let me know what is wrong in this steps. What I missed from my side. I am not able to send my transaction to multiaddress using contract.

### Currently I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: name.match is not a function
    at SolidityTypeAddress.isType (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/address.js:23:19)
    at /var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/coder.js:57:18
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at SolidityCoder._requireType (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/coder.js:56:36)
    at /var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/coder.js:231:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at SolidityCoder.getSolidityTypes (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/coder.js:230:18)
    at SolidityCoder.encodeParams (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/coder.js:88:30)
    at SolidityFunction.toPayload (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:92:52)
    at SolidityFunction.sendTransaction (/var/www/html/BlockChain/parity/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:163:24)
```

But I don't think it is related to contract. I am missing something or going in wrong way?

Please help me urgent so, I can continue my work based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `human-standard-token-abi` (which is an ERC20 contract ABI) to create your `Airdrop` contract that has a completely different functions.

ABI for Airdrop contract:

```
[
    {
      "constant": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "token",
          "type": "address"
        },
        {
          "name": "recipients",
          "type": "address[]"
        },
        {
          "name": "values",
          "type": "uint256[]"
        }
      ],
      "name": "drop",
      "outputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ]
```

That is the ABI that you need to pass to `web3.eth.contract(abi);` to instantiate your contract object.

Comment: Hello @Andrey,
I changed ABI as per you gave and it was stuck lock account so, i did unlock but now it is not returning any output or not any error return in sendTransaction functionality. I think something is wrong in sendTransaction function, Can you pls check once? is it correct or not?

Comment: Your function looks fine. Is the callback function getting called at all? If before `if(!error)` you make a line and call `console.log(result); console.log(error);` - does either outputs anything?

Comment: Yes i checked it stil it is getting nothing. @Andrey

Comment: Transaction done but it is getting fail. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x7f5bf5c2437d11d416a88a53a5f9a5a901493643cafdde5539996c586896c5e3 Why it is fail?